# How can I read data from an MS Access file and insert that data from each sheet to a corresponding SQL Server Database Table using T-SQL or SSIS?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

I have an MS Access file with multiple sheets having different types of data. I want to read data from the file's sheets and insert it into corresponding SQL Server Database Tables either using T-SQL or SSIS. I am trying to learn these concepts and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use BulkCopy.  You create two connections.  One connection is oledb to access and other connection SQLClient to SQL Server.  Then use BulkCopy.

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by a Access sheet. There is no such concept. Do you mean a table of data?